# Iterate through variables using a variable?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to find a way to iterate through a list of Strings to be displayed in a text box. These Strings are retrieved from a separate class called 'texts'. 
The Strings are declared in the 'texts' class as (for ngs1, 2, 3, etc)

```
 Public Shared ngs1 As String = "Text"
```

This chunk runs when a next button is clicked, the button's purpose being to iterate through the list of texts displayed.

```
        ElseIf firstTimeRun = True Then
        welcome += 1
        Select Case welcomePages
            Case 1
                txtDisplay.Text = texts.ngs1
            Case 2
                txtDisplay.Text = texts.ngs2
            Case 3
                txtDisplay.Text = texts.ngs3
        End Select
```

I'm wanting to be able to do this without a select case, so that it's essentially

```
'Pseudo code
ElseIf firstTimeRun = True Then
welcome += 1
txtDisplay.text = texts.ngs(welcome)
```

I'm not sure how to properly do this, by using a variable in the name of other variables. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to use a collection of any type? Vector, array, list, etc.

Comment: @AugustoQ Ah, apologies, I attempted Vectors but being new to VB they confused me, despite MSDN's attempts at helping. Arrays I've also tried but I run into a similar problem. At the time I've just been trying to do it this way, would you recommend using an Array/Vector over this, though? Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Since you already have an index for your variables yes, it would be a lot easier to create an array and access the index directly instead of creating a big select case.

Comment: I've put the Strings in an array and it does let me bring it across classes, so this does solve the majority of my problem, now it's just managing all the texts in the one array. Thank you though, a big help!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to iterate through all this texts, just create a list(of String) or array and add all the ngsX...

As Example:
`Dim list as List(Of String)`

```
Dim indexActualShownString as Integer
```

Then you can just use in your Clicked_Event

```
txtDisplay.text=list.Items(indexActualShownString) as Integer
indexActualShwonString += 1
```

But I am not sure if I understand your problem right. And you should also implement a way to reset `indexActualShownString`, since I dont know what exactly its the purpose of it.

Comment: That does help a bit, but I wanted it to bring the next one with each button click, although I seem to be getting close to solving it, thank you for the response!

Comment: Then just keep in another variable the index of the actual shown item, and every clicked event this variable goes one up...you can use the variable as a global variablo of your form or as a property in your class "texts"

Comment: I've edited my answer, take a look if you find some help now :)

Comment: Hey, sorry for getting back to you late, that does help a bunch! Thank you!